# XAML Storyboard - Binding a value to a DependencyProperty, that lives inside the same control

Tags: binding, dependency-properties, silverlight-5.0

I have set up a usercontrol with a rotating animation.

Inside my storyboard, I have a value, that determines, whether the control rotates to the left (-360.0) or to the right (360.0). The value inside the XAML Storyboad looks like this:

```
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.75" Value="-360.0"/>
```

In the code behind, I wrote a DependencyProperty, where you can set a value (360 or -360). That looks like this:

```
        public static double GetRotationValue(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (double)obj.GetValue(RotationValueProperty);
        }

        public static void SetRotationValue(DependencyObject obj, double value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(RotationValueProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RotationValueProperty= DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RotationValue", typeof(double), typeof(RotatingWheel.MainControl), new PropertyMetadata(360.0));
```

Now, I want to use this DependencyProperty as the source of the value. I tried the following:

```
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.75" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=RotationValue}"/>
```

That does not work. I looked into other cases and found, that you must set the correct data context for the control to "self". So I added in the XAML of the user control:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

**So my question is: How can I bind a value to a DependencyProperty, that lives inside the same control?**

### ------------------------------------------------------

---

Here ist the complete XAML Code:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns       ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x     ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d     ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc    ="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:ed    ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" 
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    x:Name="RotatingWheel" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="RotatingWheel.MainControl"
    xmlns:rw="clr-namespace:RotatingWheel"
    d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" Width="100" Height="100">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                                        <!--I want to bind this value to RotationValue DependencyProperty-->                   
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.75" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=RotationValue}"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.75" Value="-360.0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ed:Arc ArcThickness="20" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" EndAngle="360" Fill="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="0" Stretch="None" Stroke="White" StartAngle="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="0,40,0,0" Stroke="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle1" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="40,0,0,0" Stroke="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### ------------------------------------------------------

---

Here is the complete code behind file:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace RotatingWheel
{
    public partial class MainControl : UserControl
    {
        public MainControl()
        {
            // Für das Initialisieren der Variablen erforderlich
            InitializeComponent();
             this.Loaded += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Storyboard.Begin();
        }


#region DP RotationValue (360 or -360)

        public static double GetRotationValue(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (double)obj.GetValue(RotationValueProperty);
        }

        public static void SetRotationValue(DependencyObject obj, double value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(RotationValueProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RotationValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RotationValue", typeof(double), typeof(RotatingWheel.MainControl), new PropertyMetadata(360.0));

#endregion

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very sorry. The correct answer is very plain and easy:

This works:

```
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.75" Value="{Binding RotationValue}"/>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.75" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=RotationValue}"/>
```

Setting the DataContext was correct:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```